# ошибка отладки в MV Web developer

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, visual-studio-2010

При отладке сайта в MV Web Developer 2010 появляется страница с ошибкой "Веб страница недоступна". В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

Добавил в файл host строку "`127.0.0.1 localhost`", и заработало.